# How to use Signal-Protocol in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I use signal protocol in React?

I used `npm libsignal` but even then I got errors in nodemodules.

I tried using `libsignal-protocol.js` file from: https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-javascript and even those modules are throwing errors.

Please suggest a way to implement signal-protocols in react.

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: My main question is how to use signal-protocol in react.  [link](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-javascript) . the above link is to use signal-protocol in JavaScript. Likewise how can i use in react?  I tried two ways which was mentioned in the question. It may be bad or wrong.  Main objective is how to use signal-protocol in my react programming.. @Artem

Answer (score 0):

To make libsignal work in react (with create-react-app):

1. Put `libsignal-protocol.js` file in the `public` folder. (By doing this you're doing that the file won't get minified with the rest of the react.)
2. Add to `index.html`: `<script src="libsignal-protocol.js"></script>`
3. Use libsignal with `window.libsignal`. (libsignal is adding the libsignal to window.)