# Libsignal JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, libsigc++

What is the best way to include the libsignal JavaScript library in my vue project. I tried adding it as a script in the main.js file but when I use the keyword libsignal in my components it raises an undefined error.

Comment: What did make you think there's a way? It's server-side lib. Vue is client-side.

Comment: I'm not sure which version you refer to. This package https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsignal clearly says it's Node, i.e. it's server side.

Comment: From what I understand, end to end encryption is meant to encrypt messages before it leaves the client to the server (hence a client side implementation required). I'm using django framework for my back end and vuejs for frontend. The nodejs libsignal package does not work as it raises errors like "process.addListener is not a function). So I decided to implement the JavaScript library in my frontend(client side). Any help on how to include the script??

Comment: You need to have Node server that will communicate with client-side app (Vue or else). Your intentions may be different but that's what you get with `libsignal` lib. You cannot use it with Vue alone without Node server.

Comment: Got it. I tried https://stackoverflow.com/q/52476371 this and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For vue project you can install libraries by npm.

For installing libsignal, refer [libsignal package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libsignal) link.

Run this command in cmd in your project folder.

```
npm i libsignal
```

Hope this helps!